# How to handle default values in an inheritance chain without writing duplicate code?

Tags: java, inheritance

So let's say I have class A, which is defined like this:

```
 public class A{
    private int x;

    public A(){
        this(13);
    }
    public A(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

And then I have a class B that needs to implement y, so like this:

```
public class B extends A{
    private int y;

    public B(){

    }
    public B(int x){
        this(x, 0);
    }
    public B(int x, int y){
        super(x);
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

My question is: what do I do in `public B()`? Do I call super() so that A assigns the default value / does whatever and then do another `this.y = y` in that constructor, or do I call `this(13)`?

Both approaches seem to require some bad practices. One has me write `this.y = y` in two places. The other one requires me to repeat the default value(s) and would need to be changed each time a default value is changed.

Comment: You don't need to do anything. `B()` implicitly calls `super()`, so `A()` is invoked.

Comment: But if I do nothing, I still need to give a default value to y, which is the problem. I end up having to do this.y = y again, when I already did it below.

Comment: Oh, right. Sorry. Didn't spot that you were assigning `y`. So, you just need to assign `y` in `B()`.

Comment: How about not extending `A` but instead taking it as a parameter in `B`? This would save you some sanity if you'll want to create `C` or `D` (and essentially adding 1 more constructor for each of them)

Comment: Ah ok, I though that repeating the same code that was in `B(int x, int y)` was considered bad practice since you end up with two different constructors doing `this.y = y` . Thanks!

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev ya, that's more how I normally do things. This is part of a bigger homework problem that asks specifically to extend a class.

Comment: It seems the default value of x is 13 so why not initialize it outside the constructor in A to 13 so that you don't have to worry about in B

Comment: @DaneBrick This is an extremely simplified version of what I am dealing with. The original class sets the default values in a way that's not reasonable to do outside the constructor and would be a lot harder to implement that way. And anyways, this is a homework assignment so I can't change the classes I was given.

Comment: Ah I see, then I would say that the options you stated in your question both seem like reasonable solutions, not bad practices. Good luck!

Comment: @DaneBrick Ah ok, thanks! I've been conditioned to avoid duplicate code at all costs during my education so it seemed wrong to do it in this case. But if that's the best way, I guess I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

If the fields are not final, you could assign the default values where you declare them. So the code would look like:

```
class A{
  private int x = 13;
  public A(){
    //use default value for x
  }
  public A(int x){
    this.x = x;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  private int y = 0;
  public B(){ 
    //use default value for x and y
  }
  public B(int x){
    super(x);
    //use default value for y
  }
  public B(int x, int y){
    super(x);
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

Comment: As I said in a comment, my case was an extremely simplified version of another set of parent / child classes where declaring it outside was not reasonable since the default constructor does a lot of things that would be hard to implement outside an actual constructor. I guess I should have been more precise in my post. Furthermore, it's a homework problem so I can't edit the content of the parent class anyways.

Comment: @WinterDev then I would go for `super(); this.y = y;` to avoid duplicating the default value of x in B.

Answer (score 0):

if there is no call to an inherited constructor on the first line of your constructor then the default constructor of the inherited class will be called. If there is no default constructor then you will have to define which super constructor it should use on the first line of your constructor.

```
public class A{

    public A(){

    }

    public A(String text){

    }

}

public class B extends A{

    public B(){
        //having nothing is same as super();
        //here you can also call the other constructor
        //super(""); is allowed
    }

    public B(String text){
        //having nothing is same as super();
        //but if you add a super(text) then you set this instance to super(text); instead
    }

}

public class C{

    public C(String text){

    }

}

public class D extends C{

    public D(){
        super();// this is incorrect and will not compile
    }

    public D(String text){
        super(text);//this is fine
    }

}
```

Hope this helped.